# Itunes store: Is it normal to have no sales for other approved apps when one rejected app is under review appeal?

Tags: iphone, itunes, appstore-approval

is it normal to have no sales for other approved apps when one rejected app is under review appeal?

One of my app has been rejected. I went to the appeal board and added my apple ID, my app's name and other info to have that app review again. (Basically I don't agree with the rejected reasons and gave my explanation.) Then I found out that my other apps stop making ANY SALE! It's really spooky. I'm not selling a lot every day but an absolute zero for 1.5 week is really crazy!

Moreover I plan to upload new app. Will that one also make no sale even if it will be approved?

And how to fix this? Should I stop my appeal? And how do I do that?

Comment: I am going to answer what I found.--- Sales "should" go on normally. However, the inner workings of appeal process is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

One app rejection being appealed has nothing to do with the sales of other apps.  Jumping to the conclusion that the appeals process is impacting sales of your other is a logical error which can be summed up as "correlation does not imply causation"

For details on this, please check the Wikipedia page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation

One app being reviewed/rejected has nothing at all do with the sales of other apps [old or new] by the same App Store Developer.  App sales can go up and down if they are not managed by marketing efforts.